# HighCharts Heatmap: Plotting error with >= 1024 samples

Tags: javascript, highcharts, heatmap

I'm creating HighCharts heatmaps with lots of samples. When I try to create a plot with 32 x 32 samples, I get lots of spurious empty y-categories created.

No problem with 31 x 32 heatmap: http://jsfiddle.net/tallphil/8xattd5s/

32 x 32 heatmap breaks: http://jsfiddle.net/tallphil/fr43pqmb/

Any ideas what could be going on here? My suspicion is that HighCharts is doing something weird when it hits the magical 1024 sample number.

Many thanks in advance,

Phil

*ps. Stack Overflow insists that I paste some code here because I used a jsfiddle link, so here's the plotting code without the data:*

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: { type: 'heatmap' },
  title: { text: 'Heatmap Test' },
  colorAxis: {
    min: 0,
    minColor: '#FFFFFF',
    maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Sales per employee',
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: DATA_HERE
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [turboThreshold](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.heatmap.turboThreshold) property. You should disable it by setting it to 0.

```
series: [{
  turboThreshold: 0,
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/fr43pqmb/2/